# getting bucket access error in AWS

Tags: aws-lambda

I want to execute a lambda function whenever an item gets uploaded on S3. My function was invoked but there seem to be access error. What is the mistake?

I have defined a role `lambdas3`. Its trusted entity is lambda. It has following policy called `s3lambda`

```
Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1509114309000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1509114340000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the lambda function

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new aws.S3();

exports.handler = function(event,context){
    var bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    var key = decodeURIComponent(
        event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g,''));
    var params = {
      Bucket:bucket,
      Key:key
    };
    s3.getObject(params,function(err,data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            context.fail('Error getting object'+
            key+' from bucket'+bucket);
        }else{
            context.succeed('hello '+data.Body);
        }

    });
};
```

The function takes `lambdas3` role during execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give permission to all objects in the bucket then you have to give full permission ('*' in Resource). Please find the update policy below,

```js
Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1509114309000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1509114340000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It's an IAM role, not a bucket policy. It wouldn't give access to "public".

Comment: @Mark you are correct. I haven't noticed that. Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to add /* at the Resource S3 ARN in GetObject policy. S3:GetObject works for S3’s object ARN. For instance:

```
arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*
```